# map returns 0 for existing keys if sqlserver driver is used

Tags: sql-server, go

I have this code which works as intended as long as I use sqlite3 driver. When I switch to sqlserver, somehow, the map which clearly contains values returns 0 for each key.

```golang
log.Println(current)
for abbr, rate := range fetched.Quotes {
    abbr = abbr[3:len(abbr)]
    log.Println(abbr, current[abbr])
    if c, ok := current[abbr]; ok {
    // programm does not reach this with sqlsever driver      
    }
}
```

I added these log statements to test.

**sqlite  (https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3)**

```sh
map[AED:3.67 ARS:44.31 AUD:1.46 BGN:1.77 BRL:3.83 CAD:1.31 CHF:0.99 CNY:6.9 COP:3326.15 CRC:571.81 CZK:23 DOP:51.1 EGP:16.28 EUR:0.9 GBP:0.82 HKD:7.83 HUF:287.01 IDR:14179 INR:69.2 JMD:135.63 JOD:0.71 JPY:107.7 KRW:1162.6 MUR:36.25 MXN:18.85 MYR:4.13 NZD:1.5 PHP:51.71 PLN:3.83 QAR:3.64 RON:4.28 SAR:3.75 SDG:45.09 SEK:9.5 SGD:1.35 THB:30.66 TND:2.88 TWD:31.05 USD:1 UYU:34.65 VND:23291.5]
2019/12/25 11:42:58 XAU 0
2019/12/25 11:42:58 XCD 0
2019/12/25 11:42:58 CHF 0.99
2019/12/25 11:42:58 ZAR 0
2019/12/25 11:42:58 AED 3.67
2019/12/25 11:42:58 BDT 0
2019/12/25 11:42:58 DKK 0
2019/12/25 11:42:58 MXN 18.85
...
```

**sqlserver (https://github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb)**

```sh
2019/12/25 11:44:12 map[AED   :3.67 ARS   :44.31 AUD   :1.46 BGN   :1.77 BRL   :3.83 CAD   :1.31 CHF   :0.99 CNY   :6.9 COP   :3326.15 CRC   :571.81 CZK   :23 DOP   :51.1 EGP
  :16.28 EUR   :0.9 GBP   :0.82 HKD   :7.83 HUF   :287.01 IDR   :14179 INR   :69.2 JMD   :135.63 JOD   :0.71 JPY   :107.7 KRW   :1162.6 MUR   :36.25 MXN   :18.85 MYR   :4.13 NZD   :1.5 PHP   :51.71 PLN   :3.83 QAR   :3.64 RON   :4.28 SAR   :3.75 SDG   :45.09 SEK   :9.5 SGD   :1.35 THB   :30.66 TND   :2.88 TWD   :31.05 USD   :1 UYU   :34.65 VND   :23291.5]
2019/12/25 11:44:12 KHR 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 MDL 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 AED 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 MXN 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 VUV 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 MWK 0
2019/12/25 11:44:12 DOP 0
...
```

So for some strange reason, this map which contains the keys as logged does return 0 for everything.

Here are the 2 functions that I use to fetch and query

```golang
func getFX(db *sql.DB) (fx map[string]float64, err error) {
    var (
        abbr string
        rate float64
    )
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT Abbreviation, Conversion_Rate FROM CURRENCY_TEST")
    if err != nil {
        return fx, err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    fx = map[string]float64{}
    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&abbr, &rate)
        if err != nil {
            return fx, err
        }
        fx[abbr] = rate
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        return fx, err
    }
    return fx, nil
}
```

```golang
func _fetchFX(dummy string, dummy1 string) (Fetched, error) {
    jsn, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("data/current.json")
    payload := Fetched{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsn, &payload)
    return payload, err
}
```

If anyone has an idea why this is happening, please share your wisdom.

Comment: the second version seems to contain a lots of whitespace in the keys, which you remove in the loop, hence indexing into the map with the changed key should get you *nothing*.

Comment: oh yes, now I see it too. I didn't pay attention to that at all. Why is it bringing the stuff with so much whitespace? lol, I bet trimming this will fix the issue, its still weird.

Comment: my guess is, but i could be wrong, that you're using some constant length text type in the sqlserver db for the abbreviation column, something like `char(6)` in other dbs (don't know if sqlserver has something like that, never used it).

Comment: and as side weirdness, I created the sqlite3 DB by fetching from the SQL server and inserting the values. So they should be 100% the same.

Comment: @mkopriva, makes sense, it says nvarchar(32) or nvarchar(6), I have both tables.

Comment: if you check this out, it's always 3 extra white spaces exactly.

Comment: the values in the columns and types of the columns could be the same, however the behaviour of types does not have to behave the same, some databases follow the sql standard more closely then others.

Comment: so looks like, SQLite is not bringing the extra padding but SQL server does, `    ABBREVIATION nvarchar(6) NULL, that is the column. exactly 3 white spaces. At least it should be easy to fix even though it's annoying.
`

Comment: You could use a "dynamically sized" text type, like postgresql's `text`, or use the correct size `nvarchar(3)` if all your abbreviations are 3 characters long. Or if changing the column types is out of question do `fx[strings.TrimSpace(abbr)] = rate` inside the `getFX` function.

Comment: yes, the target table has nvarchar(32) and i think there is no way for me to change it. It's some corporate DB. I was planning exactly to do this in getFX. If you want to, submit an answer and I give you creds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the sqlserver version is retrieving the `Abbreviation`  with a lot of whitespace while in the sqlite version the abbr strings contain no whitespace. The whitespace seems to be caused by how the column's type is implemented by the sqlserver.

So you either have to change the column types so that they are more compatible with each other, or you can "normalize" the scanned abbr string to ensure that it is always formatted in the same way regardless of the RDBMS.

For example:

```
fx[strings.TrimSpace(abbr)] = rate
```